# Parse String to date, but result is different format

Tags: groovy

I have been trying to parse a string into dates, but after parsing, the format changes. I have this in my controller:

```
def dates = params.id
def dates2 = new Date().parse("yyyyy:MM:dd", dates)
System.out.println(dates2)
```

But the result is Tue Oct 23 00:00:00 CST 2012 instead of the the format that I added. How can I force it to that format yyyy:MM:dd?

Answer (score 4):

That's just the String representation of a Java Date

If you use `Date.format` to print it out, you'll see the format you want:

```
def dates = params.id

// parse is static, no need for new
def dates2 = Date.parse( 'yyyy:MM:dd', dates )

println( dates2.format( 'yyyy:MM:dd' ) )
```

(I also assume you mean `yyyy`, not 5 `y`s)

Comment: _Some_ of us are ready for the y10k problem thank you very much. :)

Comment: @JustinPiper lol! There's going to be a lot of busy programmers in just under 8000 years ;-)