# Parsing String to date doesnt work

Tags: date, groovy

I tried parsing a string in a namedQuery, but it seems doesnt work. I have this code in my domain class:

```
    searchBirthdaten{ q ->
        def dates = Date.parse("yyyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", "2011-9-21 00:00:00")
         eq 'birthDate' , dates)
    }
```

But I always got this error:

```
   Unparseable date: "2011-9-21 00:00:00"
```

I really dont understand why this is happening. Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

Your date input string has to be in the format you defined: `yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss` (corrected)

So your 3 issues were:

1. You are using the "-" character to delimit you date for parsing but your format string is using ":"
2. You have 5 `y`s in your format string i.e. `yyyyy:MM...`. Which won't be valid for another 8 thousandish years ;)
3. You define your month format as `MM` but you are passing only '9', this will need to be '09' to match your fomat string.

Comment: And you have 5 yyyyy:s... and 9 with MM should be 09... Read the documentation for SimpleDateFormat carefully.

Comment: I mentioned the 5 `y` problem in their [previous almost identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083715/parse-string-to-date-but-result-is-different-format), but it seems they either don't listen to advice, or don't read their own code.